# How can I retrieve objects in the order they were created?

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using parse to store my objects.  When I go to retrieve objects, I get the objects in a random order it looks like.  I Believe Parse isn't taking seconds into account, just minutes, and if the objects are made in the same minute it gives me the objects back in a random order.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatMessage"];
[query whereKey:@"alert" equalTo:myAlert];
```

I'm "filtering" the objects I get with a key.

I get the objects, they are all out of order though.  I can attach milliseconds to this object when it is created (dateSince1970 type thing), but I don't want to have to do that.  Is there a built in way to do this in Parse?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

yes, there is in-built feature provided by Parse. 
you can use updatedAt or createdAt attributes of the class. and you put that in query also.

> ```
> // Sorts the results in ascending order by the created date
> [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
>
> // Sorts the results in descending order by the created date
> [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
> ```

Comment: I don't think that works.. tried that in my code but the posts appear in random fashion..

Answer (score 5):

I hope it will help you

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ChatMessage" ];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
query.limit =10;
 [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
     //you will get all your objectsas per u created ur object in parse.
    }
 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse itself saves the date it was created and updated. Maybe you would want to use the date it was created.

Look at this documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS

Example:

```
NSDate *updatedAt = gameScore.updatedAt;
NSDate *createdAt = gameScore.createdAt;
```

Hope this helps you...

Edit:

```
// Sorts the results in ascending order by the score field
[query orderByAscending:@"score"];

// Sorts the results in descending order by the score field
[query orderByDescending:@"score"];
```

Comment: in my case, i needed add casting, 'NSDate* objectCreatedDate = ((PFObject*)object).createdAt;'  (thank you lakesh)